# flir thermal camera driver?

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have just purchased a flir a615 thermal camera.
we use ubuntu 11.10 with latest ROS and PCL.

has anyone made drivers already for a flir camera to be used in ubuntu / ros / pcl?
the company itself only provides windows drivers.
i've never made drivers before so if you have any and would like to share, it would be very much appreciated and +100000 karma points to u :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28788/flir-thermal-camera-driver?/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [FLIR driver](http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/flir_driver.html) (linking to doc at Freiburg's mirror, because ROS.org appears to be down) available. This one appears to be rather old however, I have no idea if it is usable with your device.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2012-02-29**:
great, thanks for the link. will test it out shortly.
and yes, ros.org was down for me too. and now pcl-users is down as well.

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-10-26**:
**Hello liquidmonkey ,
I'm trying to get the ros drivers for A65 flir , and i want to know you had the chance and run these drivers because I'm having hard time to run these drivers.
please respond to me.
Thank you**